# Modal Window in Swift OS X fails to close even with endModalSession called

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I'm fairly new to using Swift with respect to OS X app development. I have two files of interest that I'm working on.

Within "ViewController.swift", I have a **"@IBAction func newWindow"**:

```
@IBAction func newWindow(sender: AnyObject) {

    // 1
    let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let newWindowController = storyboard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("New WS") as! NSWindowController

    if let newWS_Window = newWindowController.window{


        // 3
        let application = NSApplication.sharedApplication()

        let session = application.beginModalSessionForWindow(newWS_Window)

        var value:Bool = false

        while(value == false){

            if( application.runModalSession(session) == NSModalResponseStop ){
                print("Closing.")
                value = true
            }


        }

        application.endModalSession(session)

        print("Out of loop")

    }
    reloadFileList()
}
```

From this button action, a modal window is called associated with **"New_WS_Window.swift"**:

```
import Cocoa
import CoreData
class New_WS_Window: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var nameOfWS: NSTextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do view setup here.
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    nameOfWS.stringValue = "Name of Working set"
}

@IBAction func dismissNewWindow(sender: NSButton) {

    let application = NSApplication.sharedApplication()

    addNewMember(nameOfWS.stringValue)

    application.stopModal()

}

@IBAction func CancelWindow(sender: NSButton){

    let application = NSApplication.sharedApplication()

    application.stopModal()

}
```

}

When my build runs, it opens the modal window and performs the necessary operations but it fails to close when either the **"dismissNewWindow()"** is invoked or **"CancelWindow()"**.

What exactly am I missing or did I misunderstood in implementing this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I figured out the issue, when I followed the code design off of Apple's Developer Reference, the example lacked a reference to closing the window which is handled by the NSWindow's method, "close()".